# How can I correctly allow Typescript to infer the return type of a function where the input and output object keys are dynamic

Tags: typescript

This is a working example.

```js
function doSomething<T extends Record<string, I>, I>({
  inputKey = "input",
  outputKey = "output",
  ...rest
}: {
  inputKey?: string;
  outputKey?: string;
} & T): Record<string, I> {
  // Ensure inputKey exists in the input object to prevent runtime errors
  if (!(inputKey in rest)) {
    throw new Error(`Input key "${inputKey}" not found in input object.`);
  }

  return {
    [outputKey]: rest[inputKey],
  };
}

// Example usage:
const result = doSomething({
  input: "value",
  outputKey: "out",
});
console.log(result);
```

This doesn't yet infer the type of the result, which is what I'm aiming for.

Comment: Such a type is too complex to be inferred for you by the compiler; you’ll need to compute it yourself.  What type are you expecting it to be?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvoDRw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote up a quick example of how you can do this. You will have to not use ...rest however,
as i'd at least have no idea how to infer this well and logically.

```
type ObjectKeys = symbol | string | number
function getKeyOfObject<InObject extends object, InKey extends keyof InObject, OutKey extends ObjectKeys>
  (object: InObject, inKey: InKey, outKey: OutKey)
  : { [K in OutKey]: InObject[InKey] } {
  return {
    [outKey]: object[inKey]
  } as any; // Haven't found a way to make the compiler not complain about the result being incorrect
}

const a = getKeyOfObject({ a: 1, b: "test" }, "a", "test")
a.test // number
```

Explaination:

1. Object Keys are all valid types which can be used to index an Object
2. InKey extends keyof InObject - forces the key given as InKey to exist in the given Object.
3. InObject extends object - less strict Record<x,y>, could be replaced by record if I'm not wrong.
4. Return type doing the magic.

- K in OutKey - Not sure how to correctly explain this- but what this does is map each key from OutKey (even though there is only one) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html
- InObject[InKey] - just grabs the corresponding type from the InObject at index InKey

I don't know the context of how you want to use this. However, unless really necessary I'd reconsider simplifying the function. Currently you are extracting and mapping to a new Object, I can't imagine many scenarios where this would be truly needed. A function for just extracting (with a possible throw) would be simpler to write. Or you could just use the '?' operator to do checked index access.

Small note - this function will not work with nested properties.
These require quite a lot more work. I've implemented something for  that in a little config library I once made: see https://github.com/Aderinom/typedconf/blob/master/src/config.builder.ts get function in line 99

Comment: FYI: You can use `PropertyKey` instead of `string | number | symbol`